# Installing LaTex on Ubuntu: what is the difference between the various packages?

Tags: ubuntu

I need to install LaTex on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine as dependency for [Softcover](https://www.softcover.io/). 
In the [Softcover manual](http://manual.softcover.io/book/getting_started#sec-build_pdf) it is written that building PDF books requires installing LaTeX (specifically, the xelatex executable, which is a Unicode-friendly PDF builder). 
According to [Linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-latex-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), there are several LaTex packages that can be installed in Ubuntu. The full installation (texlive-full) requires 4714 MB, which is huge, while texlive and texlive-latex-extra require respectively 240 MB and 404 MB.
The [Softcover Dockerfile](https://github.com/softcover/softcover-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) installs texlive-latex-extra AND texlive-full together, which looks odd. 
[I wrote](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/softcover-publishing/2Xqaa9WuTMQ) to the Softcover Google User Group but did not receive a satisfying answer. 
What would you suggest, considering that the documentation says that Softcover only needs the xelatex executable and I do not need the Japanese language pack? Are the xelatex commands installed by the various package different? What makes texlive-full so big in respect to texlive and texlive-latex-extra?

Comment: You could consider installing 'vanilla' TeX Live (using the TeX Live installer script, so not using any distribution packages from Debian/Ubuntu), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200209/what-are-the-benefits-of-vanilla-texlive-over-texlive-provided-by-ubuntu-reposit. However, if you do want distribution packages then `texlive-full` is the safest (although it does not cover everything, for example `latexmk` is a separate package I think). It is big mainly because it contains documentation for everything (2.0GB of pdf manuals).

Comment: You may be able to install the packages without documentation, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/latex-minimal-installation-in-gnu-linux-distributions-e-g-in-ubuntu-and-using for some pointers.